# Verify signed soap with wss4j

Tags: java, soap, unsigned, wss4j, sts

I am generating a soap request using java wss4j and would like to check if it is correctly signed. My request uses the oasis open standard and saml 1.1.

Do you have any ideas on how to check whether my xml is properly signed ?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.